# Make bold header in moderncv

Tags: header-footer, bold, moderncv

I'm getting some problems to modify `moderncv` to get the header **bold**. I would like to get **bold** address, phone number and email. Can you please tell me how can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that community members can play around with. It will make it easier for them to help you.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: Don't turn boring things like address and phone number into eye catchers by making them bold: it distracts from the things that are actually interesting (currrent and previous job titles, education, achievements). Those are the things that should stand out and capture the recruiters attention.

Answer (score 4):

If you open the moderncv theme files you will see how fonts are defined. For example, in `classic` theme (in `moderncvclassicstyle.sty`), you can find the following:

```
% fonts
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}
```

Hence you can add the customized versions by providing similar commands in your preamble.